# I want to make R codes with this SAS loop codes

Tags: r, loops, sas

I am doing big data analysis, and I want to add up each individual's physical activity.
`pha_04z1` is the number of days of vigorous physical activity in the last week, and `pha_05z1` and `pha_06z1` are hours and minutes. `pha_07z1` is the number of days of moderate physical activity in a week, and `pha_08z1` and `pha_09z1` are hours and minutes. Although it is not in raw-data, I am trying to create variables called `ph_a0100`, `ph_0200`, `ph_0300`, `ph_0400`, `ph_0500` to obtain the final physical activity amount.
Moderate or more physical activity is defined as
'in the past week, 20 minutes or more per day and 3 days a week or more' is defined.
The SAS codes for this are as follows.

```
if 0<=pha_05z1 <=24 and pha_06z1=. then do;
 ph_a0100=pha_05z1*60;
end;
if a<=pha_05z1<=24 and 0<=pha_06z1 <=59 then do;
 ph_a0100=(pha_05z1*60)+pha_06z1;
end;
if pha_05z1=. and 0<=pha_06z1<=59 then do;
 ph_a0100=pha_06z1;
end;
if pha_04z1 in (0:2) the ph_a0200=0;
else if pha_04z1 in (3:7) then do;
 if ph_a0100=. then ph_a0200=.;
 else if 0<=ph_a0100<=19 then ph_a0200=0;
 else if 20<=ph_a0100 then ph_a0200=1;
end;
-----
(Abstinence from vigorous physical activity)
-----
if ph_a0200=1 or ph_a0400=1 then ph_a0500=1;
else if ph_a0200=0 and ph_a0400=0 then ph_a0500=0;
```

Below is what I made in R code.

```
if (pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1==88)
{
  ch2020_$ph_a0100 <- pha_05z1*60
}
if (pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0)
{
  ch2020_$ph_a0100 <- pha_05z1*60 + pha_06z1
}
if (pha_05z1==88 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0)
{
  ch2020_$ph_a0100 <- pha_06z1
}
ch2020_$ph_a0200 <- 
  ifelse(pha_04z1%in%c(0,1,2),0, 
         ifelse(pha_04z1>=3 & ch2020_$ph_a0100==NA),NA, 
         ifelse(ch2020_$ph_a0100<=19 & ch2020_$ph_a0100 >=0),0,1)
```

This code doesn't work. How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance. Please help.

Comment: Its a little challenging to provide an exact answer to this question given that you have not provided data or a description of the variables (you describe the condition based on two variables, but include three or four different ones). To increase your chances of help, you may want to provide more clarity.

Comment: I edited according to comments. Thnx.

Comment: Is the SAS code or the R code inside a loop? Your R code evaluates a single line of data without a loop except for the last part which uses `ifelse()`. If you want the condition to apply to all rows of the data you should be using `ifelse()` throughout (see the manual page). Since you have provide no data and no output and no definition of "doesn't work", it is hard to say.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* ... errors? warnings? incorrect calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking data, I'll throw out some code, perhaps it'll work.

1. Realize that while in SAS, you can do a conditional reassignment with your `if` statements, in R the `<-` operator overwrites everything unless the LHS is an indexed reference (using `[` or `$`). (I do not know SAS well, so I could be mistaken in the interpretation of your code.)
2. Don't use single-`&` in an `if` statement unless it is wrapped in logical aggregators such as `any`, `all`, etc. While it currently works, the premise of R's `if` operator is that its condition must be length exactly 1, anything else is a mistake (and, in R-4.2.0, will lead to an error, not just a warning).
3. I'm *inferring* that your references to `pha_06z1` and the like are actually columns within `ch2020_`. Lack of data makes this hard to know for sure.

Three ways:

1. Nested `ifelse`:

   ```r
    ch2020_$ph_a0100 <- ifelse(ch2020_$pha_05z1<=24 & ch2020_$pha_05z1>=0 & ch2020_$pha_06z1==88, 
                               ch2020_$pha_05z1*60,
                               ifelse(ch2020_$pha_05z1<=24 & ch2020_$pha_05z1>=0 & ch2020_$pha_06z1<=59 & ch2020_$pha_06z1>=0,
                                      ch2020_$pha_05z1*60 + ch2020_$pha_06z1,
                                      ifelse(ch2020_$pha_05z1==88 & ch2020_$pha_06z1<=59 & ch2020_$pha_06z1>=0,
                                             ch2020_$pha_06z1, ch2020_$ph_a0100)))
   ```
2. Nested `ifelse`, but wrapping it in `with` to make it a little more readable:

   ```r
   ch2020_$ph_a0100 <- with(ch2020_,
     ifelse(pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1==88, 
            pha_05z1*60,
            ifelse(pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0,
                   pha_05z1*60 + pha_06z1,
                   ifelse(pha_05z1==88 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0,
                          pha_06z1, ph_a0100)))
   )
   ```
3. Assign a default value, then iteratively replace sub-indexed portions.

   ```r
   # ch2020_$ph_a0100 is predefined with some value or just NA
   ind <- with(ch2020_, pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1==88)
   ch2020_$ph_a0100[ind] <- ch2020_$pha_05z1[ind] * 60
   ind <- with(ch2020_, pha_05z1<=24 & pha_05z1>=0 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0)
   ch2020_$ph_a0100[ind] <- with(ch2020_, pha_05z1[ind]*60 + pha_06z1[ind])
   ind <- with(ch2020_, pha_05z1==88 & pha_06z1<=59 & pha_06z1>=0)
   ch2020_$ph_a0100[ind] <- ch2020_$pha_06z1
   ```